# Simple Arithmetic Operations on Binded Text Property of windows phone 8 app XAML

Tags: c#, json, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 App. In the app I'm parsing a Json data. From the parsed data, I'm populating a GridView. The JsonData consists of temperature in Kelvin. But I want to change the temperature in  Celsius while binding the data in the TextBlock.

Here's the Code in XAML

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tblk1" FontSize="20" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="tblk2" FontSize="20" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tblk3" FontSize="20" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>


        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" >
            <GridView x:Name="tempList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="10" Background="DarkGreen">
                            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding dt}" FontSize="15" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding temp.day}" FontSize="15" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding temp.min}" FontSize="15" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding temp.max}" FontSize="15" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </StackPanel>
```

And here's code from the C#

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(MainPage.jsonReturn);
        tblk1.Text = obj.city.name;
        tblk2.Text = obj.cod;
        tblk3.Text = obj.message.ToString();
        tempList.DataContext = null;
        tempList.DataContext = obj.list;

    }
```

In the output, Here the min and max temp is shown in Kelvin. How do I show it in Celsius?

> PS There's no any way to change the Incoming JsonData in Celsius. It
>   has to changed in runtime.

Comment: Well, just apply the conversion to the data. Can't see the problem there.

Comment: Also I don't think it is a good idea to mix DataBinding and direct value affectation of you controls. Plus, what is the point to set tempList.DataContext to null to affect it immediately after ?

Comment: I know, its not a good idea to mix them, but its just a demo app and I was trying the JsonParsing and DataBinding to the List. I'll only be using the DataBinding in my project. Thanks. And setting the `tempList.DataContext = null` , just makes me sure that the datacontext is correctly set. Its just the matter of satisfaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your specific question, it sounds like you want to use a converter with the binding. E.g.:

```
class KelvinToCelsiusConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value - 273.15;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value + 273.15;
    }
}
```

(Strictly speaking the `ConvertBack()` method could be left unimplemented, i.e. just `throw new NotImplementedException();`, but with the above it would also allow for e.g. editable `TextBox` bindings).

You could then use the above like this, for example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=temp.day, Converter={StaticResource kelvinToCelsiusConverter1}}" FontSize="15" />
```

…where you have of course declared the static resource in question, e.g.:

```
<GridView.Resources>
    <local:KelvinToCelsiusConverter x:Key="kelvinToCelsiusConverter1" />
</GridView.Resources>
```

(I assume here, of course, that you have declared the `KelvinToCelsiusConverter` class in the namespace which is declared in your XAML as `local`. Lacking [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to know for sure what all of the above should look like, including namespace declarations).

I also concur with the other observations made by commenter IronSlug:

- You should be using binding for all of the displayed data, not just the templated items in your `GridView` control (i.e. `tblk1`, `tblk2`, and `tblk3`, and any other controls similarly set explicitly in code-behind).
- Setting anything to `null` just before you assign it some different non-null value is pointless.

Comment: Thank you Peter, it solved my problem. And the about binding the data to other controls, I'll surely be doing that. The above codes are not my actual app codes. I was just trying the parser in the different project. Anyways, Thanks again..